# Ultrasonic Cleaning for RAM and CPU after water damage

Tags: ultrasound

After suffering water damage from a broken pipe. I would like to know if I can use Ultrasonic Cleaning in order to clean the CPU and RAM.

- 1 x Thread Rripper 2990WX (2000 Euros)
- 8 x 16GB Ballistix RAM (800 Euros)

The motherboard suffered the most. It cannot be saved. However, the CPU and the RAM could be.

**Questions**

What is the best solution to clean the RAM and CPU?

Is this a suitable Ultra Sonic Cleaner: 42KHZ + 50oC temp

Comment: Note.. I am NOT an electrical engineer. I have done research already however, I am checking here. I do not understand the -1!

Comment: if it was just water I would just rinse it with anhydrous alcohol or deionized water. Ultrasonic cleaning is to get rid of gunk that came with the liquid spill and can cause damage to the microcircuits from the ultrasonic vibrations

Comment: Why would the RAM and CPU benefit from cleaning? Water itself isn't such an issue but **corrosion** is. Corrosion causes damage you cannot remove by ultrasonic cleaning. There's a 99.99% chance that the ultrasonic cleaner is a **waste of money** for your situation.

Comment: @Arthor I agree that the downvotes were undeserved. One reason I can think of is that we like questions that could help other readers in the future, so we prefer questions that are generalizable to other situations. The link to the ultrasonic cleaner in particular won't be of much help to others, especially once it expires. Would you consider removing the link, or editing the relevant specifications into your question?

Comment: @marcelm Yes of course, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it was just water I would just rinse it with deionized water then anhydrous alcohol (or skip the water altogether). Ultrasonic cleaning is to get rid of gunk that came with the liquid spill and can cause damage to the microcircuits from the ultrasonic vibrations.

Comment: Okay, well there is gunk on them... Okay, thank you for the info.

Answer (score -2):

As already mentioned, **DO NOT USE** ultrasonic cleaning for electronic devices.
It can damage elements like ICs or capacitors. Electronic is specified for low **acceleration forces** which could be easily exceeded by UC.

If a pipe containing dirt/sewage/sediments/corrosion particles/limestone was broken, cleaning with de-ionized water should be the 1st try as already mentioned in other answers. To add some momentum, a **flower sprayer or a pump sprayer** for gardening usage set to a low pressure level could help to wipe out any dirt.

Do not use any household cleaning substances like dish washing fluid, soap, etc. 
They all **contain ions** which are difficult to completely remove without residuals.
As mentioned, pure alcohol (Isopropyl, mixed with de-ionised water) could be used.

**Contact spray** should not be used on computer board sockets, though it seems to help in case of contact problems, in the long run the contacts will corrode since it contains aggressive chemicals like acids. If contact spray is the last option, make sure to clean the part with much de-ionized water and/or alcohol afterwards, using a sprayer.